# Filter empty "headers" from text file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

Suppose I have done the following

```bash
grep 'header\|error'
```

Now I want to remove all empty header "sections". For example, I want this output

```
header 1
header 2
error a
error b
header 3
error c
header 4
header 5
error d
```

To become

```
header 2
error a
error b
header 3
error c
header 5
error d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input is as shown, that is, that all input lines are either "header" or "error" lines, nothing else....

This will work:

```
$ cat test.sh
grep -B1 --no-group-separator ^error << EOF
header 1
header 2
error a
error b
header 3
error c
header 4
header 5
error d
EOF
$ ./test.sh 
header 2
error a
error b
header 3
error c
header 5
error d
```

This script prints every line that begins with "error" and also prints the line previous to it.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point you can play with this:

```
grep -zoP 'header.*\nerror.*\n|error.*\n' file.txt
```

- `-z` - treat the file as one line, this way you can do '\n'
- `-o` - print only matched texts
- `-P` - enable perl-style regexp